# MySQL: Selecting most similar value?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table with peoples names.
I need to code a query that selects the person with the name most similar to the given one.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name='joen'
```

'joen' doesnt exist in the table, so it will return John, which exists in the table.

What's the MySQL command for this?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for `SOUNDEX` and `SOUNDS_LIKE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Sounds like what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Levenshtein algorithm computes the "distance" between words: [Levenshtein MySQL function](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552)

You can use it like this if you add that function:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE levenshtein('joen', `name`) BETWEEN 0 AND 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but this is no trivial matter. By "similar" do you mean it might be one or 2 letters off, or do you mean "Jon" should match "Jonathan" and "Bill" should match "William"?

If the latter, you might want to find or build a table that maps names/nicknames to eachother, and do a search on that.

If it's misspellings, Levenshtein might be of assistance, but I don't know how you'd integrate that in an SQL query.

Answer (score -1):

The LIKE Keyword might help you

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'jo%'
```

Selects users where name starts with "jo"

If you're programatticaly changing the query, you 
can check for the "result" and query the database again 
with the new Query by reducing the characters in the 
"name" specified.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'jones%'

SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'jone%'

SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'jon%'

SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE 'jo%'
```

Comment: This query is not make sense. Because you can search anything in `name` field. `substr` function send a lot of query to mysql, liike yours. It's unacceptable.